How I've supposed to use MVT for $f(x) - T_n$ (Taylor's) case when $n > 0$ to get remainder in desired form?
I read the OpenStax book on Calculus, and right now I'm on the chapter about Taylor's series with remainder. There is the following text (on screenshot):

I can understand that if we have $f(x) - f(a)$ (i.e. $f(x) - T_0$) then it's pretty reasonable to say that if $f$ is differentiable then $f(x) - f(a) = f'(c)(x - a)$, as the exact text said, so it's just straight MVT application on $f(x) - T_0$. And as result we have nothing but remainder in desired form of $\frac{f^{(n+1)} (c)}{n+1!} (x-a)^{n+1}$. For $n = 0$ in this case.
But I can't understand what author means in the text I have highlighted on screenshot. If I understand correctly then he said that if we have $f(x) - T_1$, i.e. $f(x) - (f(a) + f'(a)(x - a))$, then using MVT we can say that $f(x) - (f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)) = \frac{f''(c)}{2!} (x-a)^2$. Right? But I don't understand how to approach this result.
I mean, text is saying "Using the MVT in a similar argument ... etc."
Could you please show/explain how we can approach such result using MVT (if that's what selected text means)? Or my understanding of the highlighted text meaning is wrong?
Actually, I have an idea. I've tried the following:
First, rewrite $f(x) - (f(a) + f'(a)(x - a))$ (i.e. $f(x) - T_1$) as $f'(c_1)(x - a) - f'(a)(x - a)$ (since we applied MVT to $f(x) - f(a)$ already above) then factor out $(x - a)$ to get $(f'(c_1) - f'(a))(x - a)$. Then if I apply MVT to the first parenthesis, I get $f''(c_2)(c_1 - a)(x - a)$. But it's still not $\frac{f''(c)}{2!} (x - a)^2$. How to approach this?

The Wikipedia article  on Taylor's theorem has proofs for the various remainder formulas. Essentially, it is a repeated application of the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.
